# documenting django rest-framewrok using drf-ysag generates "Failed to load API definition" error

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui

I am trying to document my Django rest-framework API, I am following [enter link description here](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html) documentation.

I see some errors
first: Pycharm says **"Unresolved attribute reference 'with_ui' for class 'type'"** on schema_viw.with_ui(....). below is the code.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from rest_framework import permissions
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi

from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title="Snippets API",
      default_version='v1',
      description="Test description",
      terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
      contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@snippets.local"),
      license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
   ),
   public=True,
   permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)

urlpatterns = [
  path('swagger/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
  path('auth/', include('user_auth.urls')),
  path('api/', include('data_table.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

second: when I route to **http://127.0.0.1:8000/swagger/** I see **Failed to load API definition** error. The attached picture display[image] the exact error. How can I solve the error.

here is my settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin' ,
    'django.contrib.auth' ,

    'django.contrib.contenttypes' ,
    'django.contrib.sessions' ,
    'django.contrib.messages' ,
    'django.contrib.staticfiles' ,
    'drf_yasg',
    'user_auth.apps.UserAuthConfig' ,
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters' ,
    'data_table',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'corsheaders',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    #     'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    # ],

    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY' : 'error' ,

    # 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : (
    #     'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication' ,
    #     )
```

Comment: Got the same problem on running RDF in docker container. Please let know if you solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [ 
  path("swagger(<format>\.json|\.yaml)", schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0), name="schema-json"),
    path("swagger/", schema_view.with_ui("swagger", cache_timeout=0), name="schema-swagger-ui"),
]
```

Can you try this in the url? Also, project `urls.py` and app `urls.py` must have conflicting url paths.